# Objective: To write a program to remove duplicates from an array

Tags: c++

Hi everybody I am c++ beginner I am working on program Objective:To write a program to remove duplicates from an array. I start on it but still I think i have logic problems or i don't have the right idea I will be so happy if anyone can help me. and by the way using one function is required thats why i used .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void removeDuplicate(int [], int);

int main()
{
 int array[10];
 int i;
 removeDuplicate (array, i);
  return 0;
}

void removeDuplicate(int array[], int)
{

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   for(j=i+1;j<size;)
   {
      if(array[j]==array[i])
     {
        for(k=j;k<size-1;k++)
            array[k]=array[k+1];
         n--; 
      }
      else
         j++;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd start with fixing the *compile* problems first. All the logic in the world, problematic or otherwise, isn't going anywhere until this thing can *run*.

Comment: You need to specify a name for the second parameter in the removeDuplicate definition.  Presumably it is the size of the array.  Also, I'm assuming the cout statement and for loop are supposed to be in main.

Comment: @Namfuak Not only the second argument, he also has to specify a name for the formal parameter (the array)! What he doesn't have to specify is its size

Comment: @Abdullah0v0 What do you mean?  It's called `array`.

Comment: Also, I just noticed the for loop at the end makes no sense.  It is going to print the memory address of `array` a number of times equal to `newLen`.  Did you perhaps mean `cin >> array[i]`?

Comment: I was one click away from posting not just a solution but an *optimal* solution regarding minimal data copying, until you literally cut and pasted Tejas *answer* as your *question* code (lack of variable decls and all). [srsly? vtc.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: so why you posting this comment?? 0_o I know that u have lack of variable decls and maybe logic errors to ans that's why i post this QW

Comment: @Namfuak In your previous comment you said he has to specify a name for the second parameter of removeDuplicate definition (they are called formal parameters), he also has to add a name to the first parameter, the array! Jeffery Thomas did in his code. How do you call on it if it has no identifier?

Answer (score 1):

```
The loop to remove duplicate should be

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   for(int j=i+1;j<size;)
   {
      if(array[j]==array[i])
      {
         for(k=j;k<size-1;k++) //shift all elements one place left

             array[k]=array[k+1];
          size--; // decrease array size by 1
      }
      else
         j++; //you want to increase counter only if no shifting took place
   }
}
```

Comment: no still not working i dont see ur idea

Comment: the size i should like decleared as double or what siz=0 or what

Comment: @user3598206 size is length of your array

Comment: f.cpp:19: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
f.cpp:19: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope
f.cpp:21: error: ‘j’ was not declared in this scope
f.cpp:25: error: ‘k’ was not declared in this scope
f.cpp:27: error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: look at the code i just edited

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling a bit cheeky:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

size_t remove_duplicates(int array[], size_t size)
{
    std::set<int> numbers;
    int *end = std::copy_if(array, array+size, array, [&numbers](const int& num) {
        if (numbers.find(num) != numbers.end())
            return false;
        numbers.insert(num);
        return true;
    });
    return end - array;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    size_t size = 10;
    size = remove_duplicates(arr, size);

    std::cout << "Array 1" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int arr2[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 };
    size_t size2 = 10;
    size2 = remove_duplicates(arr2, size2);

    std::cout << "Array 2" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; ++i)
        std::cout << arr2[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

NOTE: This answer is not really for beginners.

Comment: For a moment I thought you were just going to do [this](http://pastebin.com/kMLCxqMh), but the unnecessary lambda adds a certain flare for the dramatic. +1.